# Is there a transformer like :c99extidentifier that removes underscores?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, module, frameworks

I am writing a cocoa .framework library named like "My Shared Utilities". When I set the `PRODUCT_NAME` in the project file to `${TARGET_NAME:c99extidentifier}`, it spits out `My_Shared_Utilities`. This is pretty ugly in Swift imports:

```
import CoreData // The standard
import My_Shared_Utilities // My framework
```

I want to transform it similarly, but without underscores, so imports look like this:

```
import CoreData // The standard
import MySharedUtilities // My Framework
```

This should be simple; the behavior I want is identical to the current behavior, just removing underscores. I don't even care about the capitalization, just that there aren't underscores. **Is there a transofrmer like `:c99extidentifier`, or will I have to type this manually, sacrificing possible future automatic changes?**

Comment: Here is a list of transformations: http://codeworkshop.net/posts/xcode-build-setting-transformations. I don't know if that list is correct and complete, but there seems to be no transformation which just removes spaces (or other invalid characters).

Comment: Awww bummer    Guess I'll just write it manually